# Retrieving images from a NextGEN gallery

Tags: images, plugin-nextgen-gallery

I'm not sure if this is possible but after extensive searching I can't find an answer.

What I want to do is to get all images from a NextGEN gallery so I can display them in a custom slideshow within a page/post.

Is it possible to load them into an array or edit the HTML in some way?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone interested I found a solution to what I wanted.

You simply need to create a [custom template](http://nextgen-gallery.com/templates/)

Then I accessed the images like this:

```
<?php foreach ($images as $image) : ?>
<?php echo do_shortcode('[singlepic id="' . $image->pid . '"]'); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way would be to use $wpdb to get them from the wp_ngg_pictures table and the shortcode for a single image.

If you know the gallery id then something like: (untested)

```
global $wpdb;

$pictures = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_ngg_pictures WHERE galleryid = '[id]'");

foreach( $pictures as $p ) {
    echo do_shortcode("[ singlepic id=".$p->pid." ]");
}
```

[singlepic shortcode](http://nextgen-gallery.com/singlepic/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried implementing your code but unfortunately it doesn't display anything. Am I correct in thinking that I just needed to replace the [id] with the gallery id (e.g. 1) ?